# My First Java Battleship Simulator (single array, single ship)

Tags: java, beginner, battleship

I'm new to this community and also to Java programming!
I recently picked up "Head First Java" and I did my Battleship project.

If you could kindly, give me feedback on the code?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int location;

    Battleship ship = new Battleship();

    System.out.println("Ship is 3 blocks long, ocean is 10 blocks wide, choose a number: ");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (ship.end()) {
        location = scanner.nextInt();
        ship.shoot(location);
    }
    System.out.println("Kill!\nYou win!");
}

public static class Battleship {
    private int[] ocean;
    private int shipHead;
    private int counter;

    // check if game is over
    boolean end() {
        if (counter == 3) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // creates the battlefield
    Battleship() {
        ocean = new int[10];
        shipHead = (int) (Math.random() * 7);
        for (int i = shipHead; i < shipHead + 3; i++) {
            ocean[i] = 1;
        }
    }

    // find the start of the ship
    void shipStart() {
        System.out.println("Ship head is at position " + (shipHead + 1));
    }

    // cheat sheet
    void showOcean() {
        for (int i = 0; i < ocean.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(ocean[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    void shoot(int a) {
        a -= 1;
        if (a >= 0 && a < 10) {
            switch (ocean[a]) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Hit!");
                    ocean[a] = -1;
                    counter++;
                    break;
                case 0:
                    System.out.println("Miss!");
                    break;
                case -1:
                    System.out.println("Was shot before!");
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Number between 1 and 10!");
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: One more suggestion, when you print the ocean, sometimes a location is one square, like a space, other times it's two such as in printing `-1` for hit locations making the ocean longer. I suggest using a case and printing various ASCII characters for each state instead of just a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is clear and clean, I would only suggest:

#### Opposite name

```
// check if game is over
boolean end() {
    if (counter == 3) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I would expect this function to return `true` when the game ends but it does the opposite, I suggest `is_ended` as a name and inverting the check, (then use the function with a `!` in front). Also the `if` is not necessary (`return counter == 3` is enough).

#### Separation of concerns

The `Battleship` class should return `String`s rather than printing, the main program should print. This allows easier testing and generalization to Web UI / GUI rather than console only.

#### Removing [magic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47882/20017547)

```
    ocean = new int[10];
    shipHead = (int) (Math.random() * 7);
    for (int i = shipHead; i < shipHead + 3; i++) {
        ocean[i] = 1;
    }
```

What are the numbers 10, 7 and 3? They are respectively `boardSize, boardSize - shipSize, shipSize`, so `boardSize` and `shipSize` should be arguments to the initialization method of `Battleship` to allow customization of the game to different sizes.

#### Use an Enum to associate numbers with states

When you write:

```
 ocean[i] = 1;
```

It does not mean that there is one thing there while there could be any number of things there, it means SHIP, just as 0 means NOTHING and -1 means DESTROYED. Enums are used when numbers represent concepts rather than quantities. [Here is a basic example of enums](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_enums.asp). Using them will make the code more readable.

#### Comment for off-by-one errors

Off by one errors are really tricky, so I suggest adding a comment to:

```
a -= 1;
```

To:

```
a -= 1; // User input is 1-index while Java is 0-index
```

Comment: thanks for clear review! I'll fix it and bring it back

Comment: @java_grindr I am glad you liked it, I added another point on the name of the `end` function that left me a bit puzzled. Good luck in your Java grind!

Comment: @java_grindr After these suggestions the code will be pretty much perfect! I suggest adding a 2d grid and more ships for your second review so we will have more feedback to give you!